# Pandas to_CSV break lines at a given length

Tags: python, pandas

I am outputting items from a dataframe to a csv. The rows, however, are too long. I need to have the csv add line breaks `(/n)` every X items (columns) so that individual rows in the output aren't too long. Is there a way to do this?

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K
```

Becomes in the file (X=3) -

```
A,B,C
D,E,F
G,H,I
J,K
```

EDIT:
I have a 95% solution (assuming you have only 1 column):

```
size=50
indexes = np.arange(0,len(data),size) #have to use numpy since range is now an immutable type in python 3
indexes = np.append(indexes,[len(data)]) #add the uneven final index
i=0
while i < len(indexes)-1:
    holder = pd.DataFrame(data.iloc[indexes[i]:indexes[i+1]]).T
    holder.to_csv(filename, index=False, header=False)
    i += 1
```

The only weirdness is that, despite not throwing any errors, the final loop of the while (with the uneven final index) does not write to the file, even though the information is in `holder` perfectly. Since no errors are thrown, I cannot figure out why the final information is not being written.

Comment: Reshape the dataframe before writing the CSV file?

Comment: The rows are too long for what?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a number of values that is a multiple of 3 (note how I added `L`):

```
s = pd.Series(["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L"])
df = pd.DataFrame(s.reshape((-1,3)))
```

You can they write `df` to CSV.

Comment: I won't necessarily have a full final row. I made the example uneven on purpose.

Comment: At best you could add `NaN` values at the end, so your last row would look like `J,K,` (last value blank).